# Screenshot of specific object in android studio

Tags: android-studio

Can you guys please tell me how can i take **screenshot of a specific object** in my app by pressing a button and save it.

I have created a image and you can add any text on it.After adding text i have to take screenshot of that object with the text.Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)